# How can I modify this inotifywait script to upload any file from any directory?

Tags: linux, script, shell-script

How can I modify this inotifywait script to upload any file from any directory?

I am working on an `inotifywait` based script which should check for file creation and changes recursively in a directory and then upload the modified files to Dropbox using `dropbox-uploader.sh` (please note in this environment the normal Dropbox app is not working which is why I use the script instead).

```
inotifywait -m -r -q -e modify,create --format '%f' ~/Dropbox-Uploader/name-of-folder |
 while read FILE; do   /home/user/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh \
 upload ~/Dropbox-Uploader/name-of-folder/$FILE /name-of-folder/$FILE; date; done
```

The problem as it stands is that the script will only upload files which are in the folder (`name-of-folder`) above, but it will not upload files that have changed in subfolders.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

- `--format '%f'` is not enough, it gives filenames only (like `basename`). Use `--format '%w%f'` to get full(er) paths.
- If you give `~/Dropbox-Uploader/name-of-folder` as an argument to `inotifywait` then these paths will start with `~/Dropbox-Uploader/name-of-folder/` and this will make your `dropbox_uploader.sh` invocation somewhat difficult where you specify (I guess) the target path. Consider `cd`, then `./` as an argument to `inotifywait`.
- Quote variables (e.g. `"/name-of-folder/$FILE"`), otherwise a space in any path will surprise you.

I don't use Dropbox so I cannot really debug this.

```
cd ~/Dropbox-Uploader/name-of-folder &&
inotifywait -m -r -q -e modify,create --format '%w%f' ./ |
 while read FILE; do /home/user/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh \
 upload "$FILE" "/name-of-folder/$FILE"; date; done
```